# Detect if UIBezierPath is visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, quartz-graphics, uibezierpath

I have two UIBezierPaths, one input by the user that follows their touches, and another that is pre-made. I want to be able to check if the user's UIBezierPath is *completely* covering the pre-made one.

I really have no idea how to even go about doing this, so I wanted to see if anyone has any ideas about how I could do this.

Answer (score 1):

This one's tough, because the bounds of 1 path might entirely enclose the bounds of another path but not actually cover it's contents, e.g.: the blue path's boundary (green) is larger than the black path's boundary, by it doesn't actually fully enclose it.

[image: overlapping paths]

One way to fully check, though it wouldn't be terribly fast:
1. create a new graphics context and fill background with white
2. fill path you want to be enclosed in black
3. fill the path you want to do the enclosing (user's drawn path) with white
4. check for any black pixels.

Doing this would leave the four corners of the square filled with black, so you could detect that when you inspect those pixels

Step #4 will take a second or two. you can speed it up by checking every 2nd or 4th pixel or something, or reducing the size of the context you create.

As long as you only do this once the user has completely finished their path, then you can probably  get the performance fast enough, but doing this during drawing would lag pretty good i'd imagine.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two ways:

1. Check bound of both bezier curves. If bounds are not matching, then it is sure that there is no complete covering. If matches, there is no guarantee that it covers completely.
2. Hit testing of few randomly selected points. It is not determinitics.